# VSTS Service fabric proper way to build

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS build templates and having trouble to place the necessary publish profile files into my service fabric build. So I have disabled the top and added two more steps one build and one copy. Is this the way to go ? What is the difference between two templates and where do we see that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can copy necessary files (e.g. publish profile files) to other place by using Copy Files or Windows Machine Copy Files task.

Regarding Build Service Fabric App task (top task), based on the icon, I think it is a [task group](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/task-groups), if so, you can check the detail tasks by selecting Build & Release tab>Click Task Groups> Select a task group> Tasks.

Comment: Thanks I think we should test these things in a small sandbox to see what we are missing. Wasted so much time trying to find out.